Token without value of dollar $. How to swap it back?
How can I swap a token back that does not show a $value? Status “frozen”

I’m voting to close this question because this site is for dev support, not token help

If your token account has been frozen only the owner of the token with the freeze authority can unfreeze it probably. Best contact the creator of the coin.
